# Counting number of times some words appear in a word document and exporting it to excel

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I'm looking to count the number of times a few words have been mentioned in a word document and export it to excel.
I have figured out how to export word counts and the file names they correspond to ([here is my earlier post)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66535432/exporting-word-count-from-multiple-word-documents-to-excel), but I'm unsure how to apply that to this ask.
Again, any help is greatly appreciated!!

```
Public Sub CountOccurrences()

Dim iCount As Long
Dim strSearch As String

strSearch = InputBox$("[M] [P]")
iCount = 0

With ActiveDocument.Content.Find
    .Text = strSearch
    .Format = False
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    Do While .Execute
        iCount = iCount + 1
    Loop
End With

MsgBox Chr$(34) & strSearch & Chr$(34) & " was found " & _
        iCount & " times."

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

For example:

```
Sub CountOccurrences(wordDoc As Object, r As Long)
Dim c As Long, i As Long
Const Wordlist As String = "Apple,Banana,Cherry"
With wordDoc
  Range("A1").Offset(r, 1).Value = .Name
  For c = 0 To UBound(Split(Wordlist, ","))
    i = 0
    With .Range.Find
      .Text = Split(Wordlist, ",")(c)
      .MatchWholeWord = True
      .Wrap = 0 'wdFindStop
      Do While .Execute
        i = i + 1
      Loop
    End With
    Range("A1").Offset(r, c + 2).Value = i
  Next
End With
End Sub
```

which you'd call via:

```
Call CountOccurrences(wordDoc, i)
```

in your existing code.

Comment: I also wanted the document name that the count corresponds to be added to the worksheet, but i have not been able to make this work with this code. On the code from my previous post I just added Range("B1").Offset(itemnumber).Value = ThisDoc.Name, and it worked. Any idea about this one?

Comment: See updated code. The document name is output to column A.

Comment: Unaccepting the answer simply because your question didn't specify «I also wanted the document name that the count corresponds to be added to the worksheet» is a bit churlish, no?